# How to get the user login device during the custom authentication flow? AWS Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to achieve the following user case:

If the user logged in with a new device, my app will send an email to notify the user and requires the user to enter the code in the email to successfully logged in the app.

The way I thought is to create a custom authentication flow to achieve this, but I cannot find any information about the user login device in defineAuthChallenge and createAuthChallenge.  Did I miss something here?  Is this the correct way to achieve the user case?

More info about the custom authentication flow:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/customizing-your-user-pool-authentication-flow/

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you gotten a solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to implement this using the [post authentication](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-post-authentication.html) lambda trigger. This will send you the user login details (except password) when user attempts to sign in.

Comment: This does not work since Post Authentication Lambda Trigger is invoked *after* the authentication is completed. The OP obviously needs it in the middle of the custom auth flow